# How can I create crossproduct tuple for list of n list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-itertools

For example for [[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]] I want to get tuples of 000,001...111.When I loop through list of n lists, it didn't work with itertools.product

```
product = []

for i in range(len(list)):
   product = itertools.product(product, list[i])
```

As it is obvious from the question, I am newbie in Python. Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itertools.product` works just fine for you. The documentation is quite clear but maybe you need to see it in action:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> ls = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
>>> list(itertools.product(*ls))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

If your `ls` will contain identical iterables, then you don't even need to have `ls`. Pass a `repeat` keyword argument to `product` instead:

```
>>> list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=3))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you require to get the tuple of cartesion product of list element you may change your code a bit.

```
l = [[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]]
>>> x = []
>>> for i in itertools.product(*l):
...     x.append(i)
... 
>>> x
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```